# increase the size of linux LVM disk partiton

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I'm trying to increase the size of disk to 30Gb from virtual sphere.
My fdisk output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders, total 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001c7c7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    33552383    16525313    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    33552383    16525312   8e  Linux LVM
```

After doing the steps :

```
 > fdisk /dev/sda
    >     n
    >     p 
    >     3 
    >     for selecting the first and last sector values,
    >     press the enter button twice for using default size   ( may be prob
    >     is here i missed something) 
    >     t 
    >     3 
    >     8e 
    >     p
```

it is showing like below.

```
> Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
> 3916 cylinders, total 62914560 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
> 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
> size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
> 0x0001c7c7
> 
>    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
> /dev/sda2          501758    33552383    16525313    5  Extended
> /dev/sda3          499712      501757        1023   8e  Linux LVM
> /dev/sda5          501760    33552383    16525312   8e  Linux LVM
```

why it is showing 1023 other than full size and i tried to enter with specified block values in first and last sector it is showing me value out of range. 
what i have missed..:(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question can not be understood.  You seem to have two different LVM partitions, which is odd.. one of them is only 1023 blocks long ( which is also odd ).

Comment: @psusi, I edited well, hope you can understand ..

Comment: may be the default partition in ubuntu /dev/sda2 block to 5 in between is 1023 ..

Answer (score 0):

You created a new partition, which is not what you want to do.. and you accepted fdisk's default start position, which is in the small space between sda1 and sda2.  You don't want a *new* partition at all; you want to `resize` the existing sda5.  You can do this using `gparted`.